# Concurrent users Load Testing REST API with CURL command Using Jmeter Tool

Tags: json, web-services, rest, curl, jmeter

Scenario is

1. Heroku server sends web service call to Parse.com using CURL command. web services are written as Jason and are using REST.
2. I need to test performance of parse.com server for my website in case of 40 users hitting it at one time
3. As the communication between heroku server and parse.com is through REST Jason Web services so I assume I need to generate concurrent 40 calls of each web service to hit the parse.com.
4. Each Curl command has One user session token and some parameters in header which I configure in Jmeter HTTP request when generating loaded web service call
5. I need to test the scenario in which 40 concurrent users simultaneously create project (Create project is also a web service) on parse.com (There is no web service for creating users but each curl command has a user session token as a key of each user signed up on website)

Problem:
Curl Command for creating project on parse.com has one user session. So even if I enter 40 value in thread. It will create 40 projects against one user session. whereas I want 40 users creating 40 project simultaneously.

Here is the CURL command with one user session

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: l8beiq2zv6kf420nbno8k7or1" -d '{"projectType":"feedback","users":null,"ownerOnlyInvite":false,"topicName":"SERVICE UPDATE TOPIC","name":"SERVICE UPDATE","deadline":"2014/03/08","s3ProjectImageKey":"065D417C-EEAA-4E74-BB43-5BDCED126A58"}'
```

Question:

> Should I use curl command in Jmeter for load testing or there is
>   another alternative for testing REST Jason WEb services. If I enter 40
>   user session tokens in HTTP Header while configuring HTTP request in
>   JMETER. Will it hit as 40 concurrent users creating 40 projects on
>   parse.com?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by following the steps mentioned below:

- **Using CSV**, put all the session tokens you want to use in the CSV file. jmeter will use 
  1 token for every user.
  Refer: http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

hope this will help.

Comment: But there is no field on UI for which I can write data by fetching it from csv. What about putting user session tokens as parameter in HTTP header of the HTTP request?

Comment: it does not matter what is there in UI, if your webservice is capable of handling the parameter.